# What is the type of NotImplemented?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```py
   def __eq__(self, other: object) -> Union[bool, NotImplemented]:
        try:
            for attr in ["name", "variable_type"]:
                if getattr(self, attr) != getattr(other, attr):
                    return False
            return True
        except AttributeError:
            return NotImplemented  # Expression has type "Any"
```

I'm running mypy, and it's telling me that NotImplemented is of type "Any", which it obviously doesn't like.

Is there any better type I can use to remove this error? Or should I just put a `type: ignore` in and move on? (In addition, is my use of `NotImplemented` in the return type correct?)

Comment: I'm sure this is just an example, but you should not use bare `except` or generic `Exception` when implementing exception handling in your code.

Comment: No, here in my code I actually do catch any general exception. Normally I do not, but here, it’s used since I’m using duck typing and I don’t know what the possible exceptions are for getattr if things go wrong. If anything goes wrong here, it’s not the right object.

Comment: Bikeshedding is worse than using generic exception blocks.

Comment: @cs95 I have since looked up `getattr` and made the exception less general

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is `NotImplementedType`.

```
type(NotImplemented)                                                                                                                
# NotImplementedType
```

Meaning, you can define your function like this:

```
def foo(self, other: object) -> Union[bool, type(NotImplemented)]: 
     pass
```

Now, `help(foo)` gives,

```
help(foo)                                                                                                                           
# Help on function foo in module __main__:
#  
# foo(self, other:object) -> Union[bool, NotImplementedType]
```

As an aside, it is worth mentioning that `NotImplemented` is a singleton object used with a very specific purpose (it is used to indicate that a particular operation is not defined on an object). You almost never really need to access its type, and to my knowledge there's nowhere you can import `NotImplementedType` from.

I would just define `__eq__` to be

```
def foo(self, other: object) -> bool: 
     pass
```

When `NotImplemented` is returned, it should be understood that it is a not a valid result, rather an indication that the equality comparison is invalid.

Comment: While technically true, **none of this actually answers the question.** The actual answer is: "Don't do anything." Just do `def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:`. Don't try to use either `NotImplemented` or `type(NotImplemented)` as type hints, because mypy will complain about both. Thankfully, you don't need to. Modern versions of mypy implicitly accept binary dunder methods annotated as returning only `bool` that also internally return `NotImplemented`.

Comment: You can actually import ``NotImlementedType`` from built-in ``types`` module: ``from types import NotImplementedType```. And as @CecilCurry said, ``return NotImplemented`` should work with modern versions of mypy. ``NotImplemented`` is used to inform that "a function is not yet implemented". There is also ``NotImplementedError``, which user can raise (as it is an exception) and it is used for marking that "a function is not implemented and this is bad".

Answer (score 5):

*Answer derived from a comment by @CecilCurry:*

Do not annotate `NotImplemented`.

Just define

```
def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    ...
    return Notimplemented
    ...
```

Don't try to use either NotImplemented or type(NotImplemented) as type hints, because mypy will complain about both. Thankfully, you don't need to. Modern versions of mypy implicitly accept binary dunder methods annotated as returning only bool that also internally return NotImplemented.

I tried to find where it states such in the `mypy` documentation, but could not find anything there. But from running into the same issue and trying it out: `NotImplemented` is indeed fine with mypy as a returned value of a comparison method declared as `-> bool`.